# Diff of two hashMaps in Java

Tags: java, json, hashmap, diff

I have two Json files which I converted into HashMaps. I want to calculate diff of two HashMaps and I am using [Maps.difference](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapDifference.html) which gives difference of two hashMaps. 
But my Map can contain nested map, it can contain another hashmap, arraylist etc as value.

For example:

Map1:

```
{"hello1": "world", 
  "stu": { "name": "harry", "age":11}, 
  "details": { "loc": "abc", "city": "xyz", 
               "state": "pqr", "clg": {"name": "aaa", "st":"aa", 
                "country":"aaaa"}}, 
  "value": {
            "object_type_name": 1,
            "version": 1.2,
            "subVersion": [
                   {"present": true,
                    "name": "personal/album",
                    },
                   {....}
           ]},
  "diff_val" : [1,2,3]
}
```

Map2:

```
 {"hello1": "world", 
  "stu": { "name": "John", "age":12}, 
  "details": { "loc": "abc", "city": "xyz", 
               "state": "pqr", "clg": {"name": "bb", "st":"aa", 
                "country":"aaaa"}}, 
  "value": {
            "object_type_name": 1,
            "version": 1.2,
            "subVersion": [
                   {"present": true,
                    "name": "personal/album",
                    },
                   {....}
           ]},
  "diff_val" : [1,2,3]
}
```

I want to calculate diff of these two HashMaps such that diff will display exact path and value where the difference is:

Output example:

```
 key        diff value

 -----------------------
 stu/name: (harry, John)
 stu/age:  (11, 12)
 details/clg/name: (aaa, bb)
 ......
```

Comment: What is the final output requirement? ie. this sort of diff already exists in various testing libraries for diagnostic output.

Comment: Anyway, given the start of `Maps.difference`, for each `entriesDiffering()` entries *that are themselves Maps*, also process those; would probably be easiest to do with a recursive function.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying using recursion but I am not getting exact path. I want to print the exact path like "details/clg/name"

Comment: Build the path as part of the recursion: `findDiff(Map map1, Map map2, String currentPath)` .. then `path = currentPath + "/" + differingKey`, eg.

Comment: Is there any library that gives json diff, I am aware of json patch libraries, but none does diff

Comment: can you elaborate more on findDiff(Map map1, Map map2, String currentPath). Sorry I started coding in java just one month back, not very good in it

Comment: It's a function that takes the two Maps to compare. For sake of argument, it directly prints the differences found (for non-Map differences) and calls itself recursively (for Map differences). It also takes in "the path" to the Maps being compared, eg. path will be "value/subVersion" when comparing the two "subVersion" maps - this allows the existing path information to be included in the output when comparing nested Maps.

Comment: I smell homework

Comment: Consider posting [mcve] including your implementation of ` Maps.difference` and data (maps) for testing.